# Apache Derby parsing XSLT - XALAN Error

Tags: derby, xalan

I'm making such a derby request:

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
        XMLQUERY('
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="singleOrder">
        <out><xsl:value-of select="."/></out>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
' PASSING BY REF xml_col EMPTY ON
        EMPTY) AS VARCHAR(10)
    )AS ProductId
FROM xml_orders
```

But I'm getting such an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Encountered error while evaluating XML query expression for xmlquery operator: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: xsl
```

Why did I get it?

I've heard derby uses xalan which supports XSLT.